# Why is it "How you love to hate me?" instead of "How do you love to hate me?"

Tags: sentence-structure, wh-questions

> How you love to hate me?

This is not a subject question, but why is it correct and we don't say

> How do you love to hate me?

I have same problem with this question:

> Why she said that?

Comment: It isn't. Your premise is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> "How you love to hate me!"

The above is not a question. It is an idiom used in English to provide emphasis. It is perhaps best described grammatically as an *exclamation*.

Here are some similar examples.

*What a good person he is!*  (He is a very good person!)

*Why it's you!* (I am surprised to see you!)

*How you love to hate me!*  (You hate me and you love the fact that you hate me!)

---

**EDIT**

Your title is "Why this sentence is correct?" however that title is incorrect in English. You should ask "Why is this sentence incorrect?"

Similarly "Why she said that?" is a mistake (that learners of English often make). The correct version is "Why did she say that?"

---

**Note**

I see that @Jack O'Flaherty answered at the same time as I did. I am glad to see that our answers are similar.

Comment: Just as "Why, it's you!" is a perfectly acceptable exclamation, it is conceivable thay "Why, she said that!" might also be used (or "Why! She said that?" or "Why? She said that?" colloquially). It's much more likely that it's an error, though, as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that

> How you love to hate me!"

is grammatical is as an exclamation, not as a question. It expresses surprise at your hate for me.

> Why she said that.

is not a grammatical sentence. It can be grammatical as a clause, a part of another sentence, for example:

> I don't know why she said that.